# JDBC Test connection is OK, but can't generate entity class with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I made thousend times entites without Spring Boot, but now I cant. I created a test connection, see below, it is OK, the connection is working, but when I try to connect to database with JDBC, I get the error message: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...
My test connection code:

```
System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
 Connection conn = null;
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
 String dbName = "smartstore";
 String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
 String userName = "smart";
 String password = "5293";
 try {
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

     System.out.println("Connected to the database");
     conn.close();
     System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/smartstore?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin
spring.datasource.username=smart
spring.datasource.password=5293
```

Dependencies:
[image]

Problem:

[image]

Comment: Is mysql running?

Comment: Which mysql version are you using and also how is your pom configured for MySQL.

I would suggest you follow this link, https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-part-iii-integrating-mysql-database-and-jpa-81391404046a

Comment: Yes, it's running, I use phpmyadmin paralell.

Comment: @mwKART, I used this article before. The Mysql version: 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu), the connector is  8.0.16

Comment: The problem was the time settings in mysql...